# Default to local directory if resource can't be retrieved (eg. 404)

Tags: css

I use this line to import a css style from a cdn.

```
@import url('https://external-website.com/style.css');
```

I found sometimes it happens that this cdn url returns a 404 (very rarely, but it still happens).

Is there any way to code the css so that if the request returns 404, then it should load the css from a local directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. CSS doesn't have the ability to intercept status codes for `@import` statements. You'd have to look at using javascript (if suitable to your project).

Something like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://external-website.com/style.css" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.href='local.css';" />`

The `onerror` will catch 404 status codes and change its `href` attribute to your local backup css file!